# Help identifying patio door manufacturer by code

Tags: windows

I have found the code on my sliding glass door.  It is C-276-1.  Can you identify the manufacturer for me?  I don't know how to do that.  The glass is clouding between the glass pieces.

Comment: Is that code on the glass or the door? You really want the door maker, not the glass unit maker. Any markings on the metal or vinyl parts?

Comment: Is it a vinyl door? Picture would help.